# Filter that is like low-pass filter but for intensity?

Tags: filters

Is there a type of filter for processing spectrum data that will subtract spikes in intensity? I was thinking of something like a low-pass filter but that takes away data if the intensity is too high. I am trying to do this since there is a lot of bright intensity measurements in a certain frequency range that are making it hard for me to see other data.

Comment: Note that such a filter is by construction not linear. Possibly you want to simply take the logarithm of the data?

Comment: @DanielSank I am not sure what you mean. Could you lpease explain further?

Comment: something like a median filter.  but it would kick out outliers.  you have to come up with a quantitative definition that defines an outlier.  then you need to also figure out what to do with the outlier, like remove it completely or just pare it back to the non-outlier levels.

Comment: How would you pare it back?